# Strapi v4 customize page using patch-package

Tags: strapi

I want to change the text inside login page with my custom text. I make some changes on `node_modules/@strapi/admin/src/pages/AuthPage/components/Login/BaseLogin.js`

Before editing that file, I install `patch-package` dependencies into my project. Inside project `package.json` file I added `"postinstall": "patch-package"` too.

After make some changes on file, I run this command `yarn patch-package @strapi/admin`

After finished I saw there are patches folder created and inside that folder I can saw the file which have diff code.

But, when I re run the strapi admin frontend, on login page text which I already changed still display original text from strapi.

Is there any mistakes I made on the steps ?

I used strapi version 4.4.3

Thanks before.

Comment: Have you installed the `postinstall-postinstall` package too? it seem to be required when using yarn as a package manager

Comment: Also, after doing files patching, you will probably need to rebuild your dashboard frontend using the command `strapi build` https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/cli/CLI.html#strapi-build

Comment: You can also use the `strapi develop --watch-admin` flag in case you want the dashboard to be rebuild while developing. Otherwise, the issue might be related to the changes that you added. You might want to post them on the question too. would be very useful. Good luck!

Comment: @AbdallaArbab I already install `postinstall-postinstall` and used `strapi develop --watch-admin` but still no effect in frontend login page.

Comment: You will definitely need to _rebuild the dashboard_! To debug this differently, try to add console.log somewhere into the package logic and see if it shows up when you run the development server to make sure your edits are being applied by opening the browser console. Moreover, please add some code to the question so it's clear to see which logic you edited.

Comment: @AbdallaArbab Thanks for your all information. I already solved the issues now. You're correct about the issue was related to the changes I made. I edited wrong file.

Comment: Perfect! Glad you were able to fix it! :)

Comment: Btw, would be great to post what you needed to edit as an answer to this question if you wish ofc, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For modifying texts and colors in the admin, you don't need to patch the stapi package, you should override the global  theme of your application by going through /src/admin/app.js and exporting a theme object. See the docs related to that here (V4) : Visit https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/admin-panel-customization#admin-panel-customization/

Comment: The above document is too low in customization. V3 even had more customization in HTML also than V4

Answer (score 0):

want you please try `yarn run build` after the patch folder was created. This will normally fix your problem.