# How to enable hot reload when edit in "node_modules" (Customize strapi admin)

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, strapi, hot-reload

I want enable hot reload when change content in node_modules when using Strapi.

I'm doing like this [Strapi v4 customize page using patch-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025285/strapi-v4-customize-page-using-patch-package/75955708) and it work. But everytime i want test what happen after edit. I need self turn off and run "strapi develop --watch-admin" again. How can hot reload when edit content in node_modules ?